# Build of varchar(max) command variable is truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Like many others here I don't have a lot of experience under my belt.  I've been directed to convert non clustered indexes to clustered  (No clustered indexes exist).  In the attached query I print out the @sql variable to see what my command looks like and it's only about half the tables.

1st question.  Is there a limit on how long a string that can be executed or printed?

I tried commenting out SET @sql = @sql + ' UNION ALL ' in hopes I could print or execute one command at a time but nothing printed.  I really don't want to execute until I'm confident I have the right syntax.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##ListIndex') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##ListIndex
Create Table ##ListIndex (MySchema nvarchar(max), MyTable nvarchar(max), MyIndexName nvarchar(max), MyColumn nvarchar(max), IndexType int) 
Insert into ##ListIndex
select s.name, t.name, i.name, c.name, i.type
 from sys.tables t
inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
inner join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = t.object_id
    inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id and
        ic.column_id = c.column_id
where i.index_id =2
and i.type in (1, 2) -- clustered & nonclustered only

and i.is_disabled = 0
and i.is_hypothetical = 0
and ic.key_ordinal > 0

order by s.name asc, t.name desc --ic.key_ordinal


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##ListIndex2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##ListIndex2
Create Table ##ListIndex2 (MySchema nvarchar(max), MyTable nvarchar(max), MyIndexName nvarchar(max), MyColumn nvarchar(max))

Insert into ##ListIndex2
SELECT  DISTINCT
        MySchema
,       MyTable
,       MyIndexName
,       STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT ', ' + MyColumn + ' ASC'
                    FROM    ##ListIndex TInner  -- replace with your table
                    WHERE   TOuter.MyTable      = TInner.MyTable
                    AND     TOuter.MyIndexName  = TInner.MyIndexName
                    AND     TOuter.MySchema     = TInner.MySchema
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, ''
            ) MyColumn

FROM    ##ListIndex TOuter 
--select * from ##ListIndex2


SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
    MySchema
    , MyTable
    , MyIndexName
    ,MyColumn
FROM ##ListIndex2 c


OPEN MyCursor

DECLARE @MySchema VARCHAR(100), @MyTable VARCHAR(100), @MyIndexName VARCHAR(100), @MyColumn VARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';

FETCH FROM MyCursor INTO @MySchema, @MyTable, @MyIndexName, @MyColumn
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN   
    IF LEN(@sql) > 0 
    SET @sql = @sql + ' UNION ALL '
    SET @sql= @sql + 'CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ' + @MyIndexName + ' on ' + @MySchema + '.' + @MyTable +' (' + @MyColumn +') WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON,ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [DefFG]  GO  '

    FETCH FROM MyCursor INTO @MySchema, @MyTable, @MyIndexName, @MyColumn

END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor

--exec sp_executesql @sql

print @sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to improve here. Some of the suggestions will make others obsolete (mainly # 14 about using a CTE would nullify most of the rest of them), but you said you were new to SQL Server so I will mention them all as they might help in future projects. And to be clear I have highlighted the two critical / functional suggestions. The answers to the stated questions regarding string limits (in relation to both printing and executing) are below the list of suggested improvements.

1. There is no need for global temporary tables (`##`) and local temporary tables should instead be used (`#`)
2. The datatypes for the 4 name fields in `##ListIndex` should be `SYSNAME` which equates to `NVARCHAR(128)`
3. The datatypes between the `##ListIndex2` global temp table (all set to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`) and the local variables (i.e. `DECLARE @MySchema VARCHAR(100), @MyTable VARCHAR(100)...`) don't match
4. The datatypes for the first 3 fields in `##ListIndex2` (`MySchema`, `MyTable`, and `MyIndexName`) and all 3 matching variables should be `SYSNAME` which equates to `NVARCHAR(128)`
5. The datatype of the `IndexType` field in `##ListIndex`, coming from `sys.indexes.type`, should be `TINYINT` instead of `INT` (according to the documentation for [sys.indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx))
6. The WHERE conditions of `i.[index_id] = 2 AND i.[type] IN (1, 2)` don't make sense because:

   1. You currently don't have clustered indexes so you don't need to look for them
   2. Clustered Indexes always have an `index_id` of 1 so they would get filtered out by the `i.[index_id] = 2` condition anyway
   3. How will you handle tables that have more than 1 non-clustered index? Just pick the first one? That is what `i.[index_id] = 2` does. Is that what you want? In either case, you need only one of those conditions:

      1. If you want to see all nonclustered indexes for each table so you can pick the one that is best to be the Clustered Index, remove `i.[index_id] = 2 AND` and change `i.[type] IN (1, 2)` to be `i.[type] = 2`
      2. If you just want the first (even if not most appropriate) index for each table to be the Clustered Index, remove `AND i.[type] IN (1, 2)`
7. Get rid of the `ORDER BY` on that `Insert into ##ListIndex select...` query; it has no bearing on how the rows will be retrieved from the `##ListIndex` table and is hence a waste of resources
8. The subquery inside the `STUFF` function that does the `FOR XML PATH` has two issues:

   1. You are not ordering the columns by the original order that they are in. You need to add a `TINYINT` field for `KeyOrdinal` in `##ListIndex` and populate it from `ic.key_ordinal`. You can then add an `ORDER BY` clause on this new field in that subquery.
   2. You are assuming that all columns are `ASC` when one or more could just as well be `DESC`, right? Unless you are certain that ALL of your index fields are defined as `ASC`, you need to also add a `BIT` field to `##ListIndex` for `IsDescending` and populate it from `ic.is_descending_key`. You would use this value in that subquery with `CASE` (`IIF` started in SQL 2012) in the `SELECT` in place of the hard-coded `' ASC'`.

You don't need the second `SET NOCOUNT ON` (just above the `DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR`) as you already have it at the beginning of the script

Your `@sql` variable should probably be defined as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `VARCHAR(MAX)`

Your `FETCH FROM` should probably be `FETCH NEXT FROM`

**Remove the `IF LEN` line and the following `SET...'UNION ALL'` line as they are incorrect and useless**

In the string at the end of the line where you build the `CREATE UNIQUE...`, put the `GO` on the next line

You could accomplish all of this with a CTE and get rid of the two temp tables and the cursor, but I don't have time to show that and the query as it currently is does work

Regarding any possible limitation on how long of a string can be executed: whatever you can fit into either `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (according to the documentation for [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)). I have built rather large sets of queries into an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` variable (*well* over 4000 characters) and called EXEC on it without problems.

The reason that you are seeing only about half of the tables when printing `@sql` is that the `PRINT` command will only print up to 8000 characters of `VARCHAR` or 4000 characters of `NVARCHAR`, even if your variable is a `MAX` type. In order to print it all you need to loop through every 4000 or 8000 characters (depending on NVARCHAR vs VARCHAR variable) using `SUBSTRING()`.

The reason that you saw nothing when commenting out the `SET @sql = @sql + ' UNION ALL '` line is the reason why I always recommend putting BEGIN / END markers around all `IF` / `WHILE` / etc constructs, even for just a single line to execute. Meaning, by commenting out that `SET` line, and most likely *not* commenting out the `IF` along with it, the `IF` statement then applied to the remaining `SET` and would only run that `SET @sql= @sql + 'CREATE UNIQUE...` line **IF** LEN(@sql) > 0, which it never would be ;-).

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't expect such wealth of information.  But your comments on 12 (Remove LEN statement and UNION statement) solve the issue and other comments will help me in developing better code. Also removed the concatenate of variable and command.

Comment: @ThomasAsh: yes, **12** is the functional improvement while the rest are educational. Technically none of those pertain to the two questions which were both about string variable limits, which is why I put them separate from the answers to the specific questions which are the paragraphs below the list. Either way, you said that you were new to this so I figured I would point you in the right direction :-). Please don't forget to mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAsh: actually, # 8 (especially part 1) is functional and critical, else you are likely not really copying the index definitions correctly. And I have added a little bit to both sub-parts of # 8 to be clearer.

Comment: Thanks again. In this particular case we are extracting data from a legacy system that is always ordered as ASC integers called Internal Entry Numbers (IEN). The data is coming from multiple systems though and the way we tell one IEN from another is by STA3N which is integer.  So the primary key is STA3N + IEN. Since the legacy system is hierarchical (MUMPS) it has nested tables and each nesting level adds an IEN.  So the PK of a 3rd level (3 table) SQL table would be STA3N + L1IEN + L2IEN + L3IEN and is what I'm attempting to create the clustered index on.  Do you see any issue with this?

Comment: @ThomasAsh: I hope you mean by `STA3N + L1IEN + L2IEN` is that those are 3 separate fields. And in that case, sure, sounds fine for ignoring suggestion **8.2**. BUT, you still _must_ do suggestion **8.1** else you might get `STA3N + L2IEN + L1IEN` or `L2IEN + STA3N + L1IEN`, etc. Also, why create `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX` instead of `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`? A clustered Primary Key would be better.

Comment: Yes it definitely need to implement 8.1 to ensure the order.  Thank you. 

Another gentleman also suggested a clustered primary key.  Frankly I don't understand the difference if there is one.

Comment: @ThomasAsh: main practical difference is that PKs do not allow any NULL values in any field while a UNIQUE index will. And being "declarative" referential integrity means that the intention of those fields being how to identify a single row is known to any human looking at the data model as well as any tools that look for the PK to derive structure. At the least it would benefit modeling tools but maybe also ORMs and/or Replication, but I don't recall for sure on those 2. Unless you have a reason not to, make those PKs. And add the FKs and tell the "architect" to do some reading.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio does have a limit of about 44k characters (at least for SQL Server 2008, the last time I had this problem) for select statements with a string variable.  However, the full SQL still gets executed (in my experience).

Your problem looks different, though.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but

```
create unique clustered index . . .
union all
create unique clustered index . . .
```

is not a valid statement.  Perhaps you should just end line with a semi-colon and forget the `union all`.  You use `union all` for `select` queries.

Answer (score 0):

Clustered indexes are usually your table's primary key because the table gets physically sorted by this index...which makes it a candidate for look-up queries. Everytime the indexed row is modified, index is "rebuilt" and the table re-organized, for that reason is not a good idea to modify clustered indexes and usually an integer (of any type, whether smallint, bigint, etc.) is used to identified a unique row. Same goes for composite clustered indexes.

They do have a size constraint which is 900 bytes on a maximum of 16 included columns. So, my recommendation would be to create a clustered primary key rather than converting your `nvarchar` column to a clustered index

Comment: The indexes being converted are columns that constitute the primary keys but we don't identify them as keys.  (if that makes sense)  And naturally we don't use foreign keys either.  That was a decision by the architect.

Comment: @ThomasAsh: regarding "we don't use foreign keys either. That was a decision by the architect.", me thinks you need a new architect ;-). That is a _horrible_ decision that has performance implications in addition to the obvious data integrity issues.

Comment: No argument here.  Our legacy DW uses keys extensively.  Different architect.

Comment: I'm not savvy enough to be aware of performance implications of not defining primary keys.  Care to enlighten me?  In our legacy DW I assumed they were protections from dropping tables & indexes but nothing to do with performance.

Comment: @ThomasAsh: having FKs allows the query optimizer to eliminate certain operations under certain conditions. And they make sure that you don't have orphaned data. They are only performance issues on massive INSERT operations, but they can be disabled during those operations and re-enabled later. PS: Just FYI, if you are addressing someone who is not the person who submitted the answer (or whatever you are commenting on) then you need to start with @ and the persons username else they won't be notified of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on using `UNION ALL` with dynamic SQL.

If you need to join several queries or batches, you just concatenate strings like

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT 1 ' + ' SELECT 2 '
```

When you are creating a statement using `UNION ALL` and you do not know how many SELECTs there will be (or you don't want to bother about that) - create a string ending with `UNION ALL` and then cut last 9-10 characters.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT 1 AS col FROM MyTable' + ' UNION ALL ' + ... + ' SELECT 1 FROM MyTable UNOIN ALL'
SET @sql = LEFT (@sql, len(@sql) - 10
```